# Taking input from command line as well as console(STDIN) in C

Tags: c

I am a beginner in coding and having difficulty trying to take input from both command line as well as console(STDIN).  my program is supposed to search and replace a group of characters from a string. For example, concatenate cat gat : the output must be congatenate!

This is my code so far!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*Function to replace a string with another string*/

char *rep_str(const char *s, const char *old, const char *new1)
{
    char *ret;
    int i, count = 0;
    int newlen = strlen(new1);
    int oldlen = strlen(old);

    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)    
    {
        if (strstr(&s[i], old) == &s[i]) 
        {
            count++;
            i += oldlen - 1;
        }
    }
    ret = (char *)malloc(i + count * (newlen - oldlen));
    if (ret == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    i = 0;
    while (*s)
    {
        if (strstr(s, old) == s) //compare the substring with the newstring
        {
            strcpy(&ret[i], new1);
            i += newlen; //adding newlength to the new string
            s += oldlen;//adding the same old length the old string
        }
        else
        ret[i++] = *s++;
    }
    ret[i] = '\0';
    return ret;
}
int main(int argc, char*agrv[])
{
    char mystr[100], c[10], d[10];
    scanf("%s", mystr);

    scanf(" %s",c);

    scanf(" %s",d);


    char *newstr = NULL;


    newstr = rep_str(mystr, c,d);
    printf("%s\n", newstr);
    free(newstr);
    return 0;
}
```

as for now, it shows correct output for either console input or commandline input, bur not both!

kindly suggest the changes to be made!

Comment: always be specific about your problem and show what you have tried so far

Comment: This is quite vague to answer. Why don't you post what exactly your program is doing?

Comment: There is no command line processing in your program. How exactly do you invoke your program? Make that clear in your question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a check on the variable `argc` of function `int main()`.

```
// Path of executable file is passed by default so value of 'argc' will be at least 1
if(argc > 1) 
{
   // do stuff to work on input from command line
}else{
   // do stuff to work on input from STDIN
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to parse input file through argc and argv, simply pass all the input file through stdin. This means that you will always use scanf to read input data.

At command line you will need to call using pipes, something like this:

```
$ cat file.txt | yourprogram
```